# Как подключаться скриптом к памяти azure blob?

Tags: powershell, azure

Задача стоит в создании файла, при запуске которого будет автоматически копироваться данные с подключённой карты памяти к пк на облако. На данный момент имею скрипт при запуске которого файлы переносятся в облако, но перед этим нужно подключаться к азуру через свой аккаунт. 
А скрипт необходимо запускать на множестве разных пк постоянно. Запускать будут люди, которым нужно просто двойной клик по иконке и все. 
Есть ли возможность сделать все это дело через ключи или апи и тд? 
Если да, буду благодарен за пример или просто на гайд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не рекомендую использовать ключи. Ключи не должны раздаваться клиентам.
Для этого лучше использовать [SAS Tokens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1). В дополнении, SAS токенами можно контролировать обозначив их длительность и доступ к определенным ресурсам на Blob Storage при помощи [Stored Access Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#controlling-a-sas-with-a-stored-access-policy). Есть и [пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2) как используется.